# How to fix issues with broken sourcemaps in stylus after FontFace rule

Tags: font-face, stylus, source-maps

I am working with Stylus + webpack 2. I am using sourcemaps and it was working fine till I added a @font-face with outer fonts rule.

Now my source maps isn't working. Maybe someone knows anything about that and how it can be fixed? Thank for any help!

Here is my code

```
$relativePathToAssets = "../"

@font-face {
  font-family: 'YanoneKaffeesatzBold';
  src: url($relativePathToAssets + 'fonts/yanoneKaffeesatz_bold/YanoneKaffeesatz-Bold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src:    url($relativePathToAssets + 'fonts/yanoneKaffeesatz_bold/YanoneKaffeesatz-Bold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
          url($relativePathToAssets + 'fonts/yanoneKaffeesatz_bold/YanoneKaffeesatz-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
          url($relativePathToAssets + 'fonts/yanoneKaffeesatz_bold/YanoneKaffeesatz-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
          url($relativePathToAssets + 'fonts/yanoneKaffeesatz_bold/YanoneKaffeesatz-Bold.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in the comments. It should be removed and after that all sourcemaps will be working fine.